# How can we display the edit account form using shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, shortcode

How can we display the edit account form using shortcode? I believe we should create a new function, and I think we will put this at the end of the function: `add_shortcode ('display-edit-account-form', 'display_edit_account_form');`.

```
//[display-edit-account-form]
function display_edit_account_form() {
    
    return edit account form;
}
add_shortcode ('display-edit-account-form', 'display_edit_account_form');
```

This is my edit account form code from my form-edit-account.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" /> <span><em><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in your profile', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php esc_html_e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed `form-edit-account.php` template (My account "edit account") in a shortcode, can use:

```
add_shortcode('edit_account', 'display_myaccount_edit_account');
function display_myaccount_edit_account()
{
    return WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_account();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:** `[edit_account]`

Comment: thank you very much. Now we can apply this in other similar scenarios.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for the above code. But here once we add a shortcode in custom template after saving the form it id being redirected to the end point of edit account. Can skip redirect and save form in the same custom page. I added question [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118720/woocommerce-save-billing-address-without-redirecting-to-end-point-using-edit-add)