# How to display WooCommerce My account dashboard using a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, shortcode

I have a custom myaccount page and I want to display dashboard.php in it. How can we embed `dashboard.php` template (My account "dashboard") in a shortcode?

Based on *[How can we display the edit account form using shortcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748334/how-can-we-display-the-edit-account-form-using-shortcode/62753755#62753755)* answer to my previous question, I tried the following in my `functions.php`:

```
//[account_dashboard]
add_shortcode('account_dashboard', 'display_account_dashboard');
function display_account_dashboard()
{
    return WC_Shortcode_My_Account::dashboard();
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Just updated my code… There was something missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** *Added missing defined [argument "current_user"](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L3028-L3034)*.

To get the template `myaccount/dashboard.php` embedded in a shortcode you will use the function `wc_get_template()` this way:

```
add_shortcode('account_dashboard', 'display_account_dashboard');
function display_account_dashboard()
{
    return wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/dashboard.php',
        array(
            'current_user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() )
        )
    );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:** `[account_dashboard]`